# Update tables using dropdown: R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dropdown, shiny-reactivity

I have a large dataset with data in rows associated with a name. I have a dropdown that is the list of all the names. I have multiple tables displaying different portions of information in association with the given name. When the user changes the name from the dropdown, I want the tables to update with the proper information for the new name.

I have the dropdown working and graphs changing accordingly but I can't get the tables to change.

```
function( input, output, session ) {


# Dropdown

output$namesDrop<- renderUI({
  names <- my_data$'name'
  selectInput( "SearchedName", "Select Name", names ) })


# Vars

GivenName <- reactive({ input$SearchedName })
SelectedNameInfo <- reactive({ my_data[my_data$'name' == GivenName(), ] })
GivenNameNum <- reactive({ SelectedNameInfo()$`Name ID` })
SelectedProfile <- reactive({ Profile[c( Profile$'Name ID' == GivenNameNum() ),] })


# Table Op 1
# With "GivenName <- 'Tom'" this code worked and before putting the vars in reactives

NameAgeTable <- cbind( SelectedProfile$'Age', SelectedNameInfo$'Birth' )
rownames(NameAgeTable) <- c('Age:','Birth:')
colnames(NameAgeTable) <- 'Age Info'
output$NameAgeTable <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(NameAgeTable, options = list( dom = "ft"
    ,fixedHeader = TRUE, pageLength = 2, info = FALSE, lengthChange = FALSE
    ,searching = FALSE, ordering = FALSE))})


# Table Op 1
# I would have assumed this but it didn't work. I tried different variations of reactive({ }),
# SelectedProfile()$'Age', SelectedProfile()[,'Age'] and none of it worked

NameAgeTable <- reactive({ cbind( SelectedProfile()$'Age', SelectedNameInfo()$'Birth' )
rownames(NameAgeTable) <- c('Age:','Birth:')
colnames(NameAgeTable) <- 'Age Info'
as.data.frame(NameAgeTable) })
output$NameAgeTable <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(NameAgeTable, options = list( dom = "ft"
    ,fixedHeader = TRUE, pageLength = 2, info = FALSE, lengthChange = FALSE
    ,searching = FALSE, ordering = FALSE))})

}
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)